# RSpec devise - cannot sign_in for user created by seed data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

To test controller, I was using following code to authenticate user created by using seed data. All test cases were failing with 401

```
def login_user
  before(:each) do
    user = User.find_by_email('iberp@gmail.com')
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    sign_in  user # Using factory girl as an example
  end
end
```

the issue is resolved after making user as instance variable (@user). why user needs to be instance variable ? sign response is n't sufficient to set cookies?

Comment: Try changing your `sign_in` line to: `sign_in :user, user`

Comment: Side note, storing data in the test DB is generally a bad idea. Look into using FactoryGirl to create data on the fly.